# Disable one input in a dynamically generated <tr> with two inputs, one of them a dropdown

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-templates

I have a recipe app in DJango with an inline-formset-factory. I use this to dynamically add ingredients to my recipe.
The ingredient table has three inputs:

A rum, an item and an amount.
I now want to disable either rum or item depending on which one has a value enterd.
If rum has a value, items should be disabled an the other way around.
How can I get this done? I've been experimenting with an each loop but I really struggle get get anything useful out of it.
Any help and pointers on learning to get better with jquery loops for things like this would be much appreciated.

See my HTML code below:

```
<tbody id="item-ingredients">  <!-- id="item-inlineformsetname" -->
                    <!-- formset non forms errors -->                        
                        
                        <tr id="ingredients-0" class="hide_all">  <!-- id="inlineformsetname-counter" -->
                            <input type="hidden" name="ingredients-0-id" id="id_ingredients-0-id">
                            
                                <td>
                                    <select name="ingredients-0-ingredient_rhum" class="rhum ingredient-input" id="id_ingredients-0-ingredient_rhum">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="1">Original - 50.0</option>

  <option value="2">Se Mettre Au Vert - 44.0</option>

  <option value="5">Se Mettre Au Vert - 68.0</option>

</select>
                                       
                                </td>
                            
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="ingredients-0-ingredient_name" class="items ingredient-input" maxlength="255" id="id_ingredients-0-ingredient_name">
                                       
                                </td>
                            
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="ingredients-0-ingredient_amount" step="0.1" id="id_ingredients-0-ingredient_amount">
                                       
                                </td>
                            
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients-0-DELETE" id="id_ingredients-0-DELETE">
                                       
                                </td>
                            

                        </tr>
                    
                </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the following code should work. I'm not using ajax even though your question has this tag, so feel free to give more details if this doesn't answer your question.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_ingredients-0-ingredient_rhum, #id_ingredients-0-ingredient_name').on('change keyup', function() {
    if ($('#id_ingredients-0-ingredient_rhum').val() !== '') {
      $('#id_ingredients-0-ingredient_name').prop('disabled', true);
    } else if ($('#id_ingredients-0-ingredient_name').val() !== '') {
      $('#id_ingredients-0-ingredient_rhum').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#id_ingredients-0-ingredient_name, #id_ingredients-0-ingredient_rhum').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody id="item-ingredients">
  <!-- id="item-inlineformsetname" -->
  <!-- formset non forms errors -->

  <tr id="ingredients-0" class="hide_all">
  
    <!-- id="inlineformsetname-counter" -->
    <input type="hidden" name="ingredients-0-id" id="id_ingredients-0-id">

    <td>
      <select name="ingredients-0-ingredient_rhum" class="rhum ingredient-input" id="id_ingredients-0-ingredient_rhum">
        <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
        <option value="1">Original - 50.0</option>
        <option value="2">Se Mettre Au Vert - 44.0</option>
        <option value="5">Se Mettre Au Vert - 68.0</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="ingredients-0-ingredient_name" class="items ingredient-input" maxlength="255" id="id_ingredients-0-ingredient_name">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="ingredients-0-ingredient_amount" step="0.1" id="id_ingredients-0-ingredient_amount">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients-0-DELETE" id="id_ingredients-0-DELETE">
    </td>

  </tr>

</tbody>
```

---

EDIT

To address your comment: if items are added dynamically, I think you'd be better off using classes in your jQuery code rather than trying to identify an incrementing ID. The following code uses the classes in your example:

```js
// Get the rum and item inputs
const rumInput = $('.rhum.ingredient-input');
const itemInput = $('.items.ingredient-input');

// Listen for changes on the rum input
rumInput.on('change', () => {
  if (rumInput.val() !== '') {
    itemInput.prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    itemInput.prop('disabled', false);
  }
});

// Listen for changes on the item input
itemInput.on('input', () => {
  if (itemInput.val() !== '') {
    rumInput.prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    rumInput.prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody id="item-ingredients">
  <!-- id="item-inlineformsetname" -->
  <!-- formset non forms errors -->

  <tr id="ingredients-0" class="hide_all">
  
    <!-- id="inlineformsetname-counter" -->
    <input type="hidden" name="ingredients-0-id" id="id_ingredients-0-id">

    <td>
      <select name="ingredients-0-ingredient_rhum" class="rhum ingredient-input" id="id_ingredients-0-ingredient_rhum">
        <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
        <option value="1">Original - 50.0</option>
        <option value="2">Se Mettre Au Vert - 44.0</option>
        <option value="5">Se Mettre Au Vert - 68.0</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" name="ingredients-0-ingredient_name" class="items ingredient-input" maxlength="255" id="id_ingredients-0-ingredient_name">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="ingredients-0-ingredient_amount" step="0.1" id="id_ingredients-0-ingredient_amount">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients-0-DELETE" id="id_ingredients-0-DELETE">
    </td>

  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: This works!
However: It's a dynamically added td so the number 0 increases. Is there a way to do something like this?

var count =  $('#id_ingredients-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value')

 $('#id_ingredients-'+count+'-ingredient_rhum)

Comment: @ThomasDoll-Datema I made an edit to my answer to address your comment :)